# SmartGWT Canvas getPrintHTML

Tags: gwt, smartgwt

We are facing problem with our widget which we want to conver to a PDF. The widget has some custom images and a custom hotspot widget to it. It works fine on the browser.

But when we call getPrintHTML, it is ignoring the images and printing everything else. The HTML for the widgets seems to contain DIV's with the images being styled as background images (instead of foreground images).

Questions:

1. Does Canvas.getPrintHTML ignore background images?
2. Is there a way to over-ride or work around this behaviour?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at the SmartGWT EE Javadoc.

http://www.smartclient.com/smartgwtee/javadoc/com/smartgwt/client/docs/Printing.html

The print properties maybe ? http://www.smartclient.com/smartgwtee/javadoc/com/smartgwt/client/util/PrintProperties.html

Comment: Thanks. While your answer has not solved my problem it gave me an important clue. I had looked at printproperties earlier but missed an important point. Basically, it was not the images but the fact that SmartGWT ignores "absolute" positioned widgets that is a problem. They have fixed this in version 3.1d but I am having trouble installing that and checking. Thanks for the clue.